# What do we call to the person who can write many words in a day?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

While writing a blog, a question struck my mind:

> What do we call to the person who can write many words, say 3000-5000 words, in a day?

I tried to google the answer but failed. Is there any word in English for such a strong writer?

Comment: A person who produces a significant output of words is called a **writer**.  There's no specific word that defines the output as having to occur within a single day.

Comment: Some kind of an **enthusiast**?

Comment: There are also journalists known as **hacks** who can bang out that many words a day.

Comment: It might be worth noting that _hack_ is typically used pejoratively. Another term that might be used is **author**, which would be more respectful than condescending. I like what @Tᴚoɯɐuo said, there’s not really a word for this; rather than focusing on the word for the person, you’d probably be better off looking for a suitable adjective, such as _prolific, accomplished,_ or _productive_.

Comment: A hack is condescending. For sure. A person can write 5,000 words a day and be writing dime-store romances or crap literature. We were asked for another term, not for a  positive one, if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the number you gave represents an unusually high output (and that's what you're trying to describe), then they could be said to be [**prolific**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prolific):

> marked by abundant inventiveness or productivity · a *prolific* composer
>
> producing a large amount of something

Comment: The extent to which an author is prolific is usually measured by their number and length of published works, not the daily rate at which they produce first draft material.  Fortunately, if the author's first drafts are nonredundant and of good quality, authors who write quickly are more likely to have lots of published material than authors who write slowly.

Answer (score 1):

prolific, productive, dedicated, consumed (by the writing project to the extent of all else), focused, clear-headed, flowing as in "with flowing, easy prose" or "overflowing with words"